How to show Exception with a custom response template
I am using Asp.net framework C# application trying to throw a Custom Exception extends Exception
while throw a new Exception using new CustomExceptionHandler(ExceptionEnums.UnableToProcess); I get response in this format
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "",
    "ExceptionType": "",
    "StackTrace": null,
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": " aMessage",
        "ExceptionType": "Exception type message ",
        "StackTrace": "  Stak trace Message .. ",
        "InnerException": {
            "Message": "An error has occurred.",
            "ExceptionMessage": "One or more errors occurred.",
            "ExceptionType": "Exception type message",
            "StackTrace": "  Stack trace message..",
            "InnerException": {
                "Message": "An error has occurred.",
                "ExceptionMessage": "...",
                "ExceptionType": "..",
                "StackTrace": ".."
            }
        }
    }
}

I want the response to be {Message:"My Custom Message"} how can I achieve this
I tried overriding ToString and call it try { code block } catch(CustomException ex) {ex.Tostring()} but since some methods has return type of  Task<MyResponse> MethodName (int variable, string username) I get error cannot implicitly covert string to MyResponse message

Try to use Exception base constructor that accept one string parameter which is a message

This question is similar to: ASP.NET Core Web API exception handling. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
